# My API gateway UI is different from others

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am following some tutorial and the video says "Go to your resource tab". But I could not find the resource in my UI. I realize I have a different UI than other people.

Ihis is the API gateway UI I saw other people have.
[image]

But my API Gate UI is [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one you have created is a HTTP API so that have different UI but the one you are looking at from the tutorial is for HTTP Rest API. If you create a REST API you should be able to follow the tutorial. Thanks!